# how to apply css to datatable scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I use datatable API for tables.

```
$('#datatable-example').dataTable({

     "scrollX": true,
     "info" : false,
     "fnDrawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
            $('td').removeClass('sorting_1');
     }
 });
```

I tried to extract the datatable scrollbar class and apply custom css. I didnt find any particular css also for scrollbars. How to apply styles to custom scroll bars?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) .

You can use this plugin after running Datatable and improve your personal knowledge with CSS

```
$('#datatable').dataTable({
  "fnInitComplete": function() {
    $('#datatable').find('.dataTable_scrollbar').jScrollPane();
  },
  "sScrollY": "500px"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try this for webkit browsers

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

Comment: they haven't apply the css to scrollbars but div

Comment: Sorry my mistake have you tried this for webkit browsers